# Node.js + Python Child Process: Print returns data, but return doesn't

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, sockets

I have a basic question.  I'm writing beginning code with node.js + socket.io, in which I use a python child process and trigger actions when it returns data, viz:

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket) {
    socket.on('load_api_call', function() {

        var pythonarray=['/Users/<omitting path>/test_return_sub_dict.py']

        var child=spawn('/Users/<omitting path>/python2.7',pythonarray)

        child.stdout.on('data',function(data){
            socket.emit('jsonSuccess',data.toString('utf8'));           
            console.log('python output: '+data);
        });

        child.stderr.on('data',function(data){
            process.stdout.write('error output: '+data);
        });

    });
});
```

This works fine.  My question is this: when I print the data returned by in my python child process, the above "child.stdout.on('data'" will be activated by the returning data.  However, when I just "return" the data, no data is returned, or anyway isn't returned in a way socket can hear.  So for example in my child process module called "return sub dictionary", the last line

```
return sub_dict
```

will not return anything that socket will notice.  But this last line:

```
print sub_dict
```

would be noticed by socket and trigger the subsequent desired actions.

What is the correct way to return data from a python child process such that node will notice it?

I can see that I'm not understanding some basic mechanism here of Python, Node, or both, but I don't know what to call it to google an answer.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python script has to output to stdout or stderr for node to pick data up because those are the streams that the child process object is watching. AFAIK just returning a value does not automatically display that data, so you have to tell python to manually print to stdout or stderr.

Comment: Thanks!  I believe you, based on what I've read since then and what my hacker friends tell me.  I'll count this as correct.